# Creating a vertical responsive navigation bar using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently trying to create a website from scratch, seen as I have the time to practice.

So far, I have got a working navigation bar (one which does not actually take you to other pages yet but does actually work ).

I decided to make this navigation bar responsive, as it is quite a big bar.
I have given the option of a vertical bar at a click of a button.
To note, the button is only available to the user when the browser is less than 900px width.

My current issue is that when the button is pressed, nothing is being displayed. I have ensured the javascript for the button is working, via trial and error but still have no luck.

I am new to this, so forgive me if my error is silly but any help would be greatly appreciated.

To help give an idea of what I am trying to achieve, here is the link I have been using as guidance: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp

If the issue lays within the fact that I am using an 'unordered list' tag to align my navigation bar to the right and my logo to the left, then any alternative way is welcome too!

Thank you.

P.s. ignore the names of each section in the navigation, I was just filling in the spaces for now ^^

```css
body{
 background-color: grey;
 margin:0;
}

/*----------------------NAVIGATION BAR----------------------*/
.nav-container{
 background-color: white;
 float: right;
 height: 80px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0;
}
#nav-menu{
 float:right;
 padding: 13px 13px; 
}

#nav-menu li{
 display:inline-block;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 text-align: center;
}
#nav-menu li a:not(.nav-active){ 
 color: black; 
 text-decoration: none;
}
#nav-menu li a:hover:not(#logo){
 color: #0aaaa0; 
}
.nav-active {
 color: #0aaaa0;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/* LOGO */

#logo{
 padding: 0px 13px;
 float: left;
 font-size: 27px;
}
/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
#nav-menu .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #nav-menu li a:not(.icon) {display: none;}
  #nav-menu li a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .nav-bar.responsive {position: relative;}
  .nav-bar.responsive li a.icon{
   position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .nav-bar.responsive li a{
 float: none;
 display: block;
  text-align: left;
 position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css">
 <!-- Load an icon library to show a hamburger menu (bars) on small screens -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>
<!-- NAVIGATION BAR -->
<div  class="nav-container">
 <ul id="logo">Dellion</ul>
 <ul class="nav-bar" id="nav-menu">  
  <li><a class="nav-active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="cars.html">Cars</a></li>
  <li><a href="charities.html">Charities</a></li>
  <li><a href="pros.html">Pros</a></li>
  <li><a href="pros.html">Games</a></li>
  <li><a href="auctions.html">Auctions</a></li> 
  <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
  <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nav-menu");
  if (x.className === "nav-bar") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "nav-bar";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The styling for `responsive` will only work if the screen width is smaller then 900px

Comment: Firstly, thank you for taking the time to respond.
 
As I stated, "To note, the button is only available when the browser is less than a specific size". 
I intentionally made it so that the button (icon) to bring about the responsive styling, would not be available unless the browser is of a size of 900px or less.
My issue is that the styling is not occurring when the button is clicked.

Comment: I have updated the post to make my issue and goal clearer.

Comment: You have [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issues in your CSS, such as `#nav-menu li a:not(.icon) {display: none;}` in your media query. ID selectors beat class selectors, so this style persists. I would suggest using class selectors for all of your declaration blocks. You also might want to give class names to the elements you need to select instead of chaining selectors. For example, give your `<a>` tags the class `nav-bar__link`.

Comment: Ohh I didn’t realise ID selectors would take priority over classes but now having said that, makes a lot of sense! Regarding the class names, I’ll definitely give that a go! Thank you ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify your layout by using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nav-menu");
  if (x.className === "nav-bar") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "nav-bar";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#logo {
  font-size: 27px;
  padding: 0 13px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.nav-bar {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.nav-bar li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-bar a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-links {
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.hamburger .icon {
  /* remove the styling, this code is for illustration purpose only*/
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.nav-bar,
.hamburger .icon {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 901px) {
  .nav-bar,
  .nav-bar.responsive {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .hamburger .icon {
    display: block
  }
  .nav-bar.responsive {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .nav-links {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .nav-bar li {
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <div id="logo">Dellion</div>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <ul class="nav-bar" id="nav-menu">
      <li><a class="nav-active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="cars.html">Cars</a></li>
      <li><a href="charities.html">Charities</a></li>
      <li><a href="pros.html">Pros</a></li>
      <li><a href="pros.html">Games</a></li>
      <li><a href="auctions.html">Auctions</a></li>
      <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="hamburger">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer to my question! I realise that my biggest mistake was not using Flexbox and I had unnecessary css command lines that if anything, were doing me more bad than good. Thank you for this reply, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @GeekPolice: Glad this helped, you can accept the answer if this solved your actual issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple way:

```
.nav-container{
    background-color: white;
    /* float: right; */
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#nav-menu{
    /* float:right; */
    /* padding: 13px 13px;   */
}

#nav-menu li{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav-menu li a:not(.nav-active){    
    color: black;   
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav-menu li a:hover:not(#logo){
    color: #0aaaa0; 
}
.nav-active {
    color: #0aaaa0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* LOGO */

#logo{
    padding: 0px 13px;
    /* float: left; */
    font-size: 27px;
}
/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
#nav-menu .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

And I recommended you to read [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) useful article about css Flexbox.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I’m very surprised I hadn’t come across Flexbox before! The navigation bar actually keeps within its own div now, which is a big relief ^^ thank you also for the link, they have a very good explanation on there.

Comment: Your welcome! If my answer was helpful, please accept it (click in the checkmark on the left top side of this answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your problem is, :

Javascript:

```
 if (x.className === "nav-bar") {
    x.className += " responsive"; //add space after quotation mark, otherwise class is added adjacent
  } else {
    x.className = "nav-bar";
  }
```

Css:

```
.nav-bar.responsive li a{
    float: none;
    display: block !important; /* I think this needs to be crushed with important */
  text-align: left;
    /* position: relative; you don't need it */
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it with css

```
flex-direction: column;
```